# How to invoke one component action from other component Using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my accord component action:

`accord.js`

```
const toggle = useCallback(() => {
  if (!disabled) {
    setExpand((expand) => !expand);
  }
}, [disabled, setExpand]);

<div className={`Accord`} onClick={toggle} >
```

How to invoke accord action from other components?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using custom hooks:

`useAccord.js`

```
const useAccord = (disabled) => {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  const toggle = useCallback(() => {
    if (!disabled) {
      setExpand((expand) => !expand);
    }
  }, [disabled, setExpand]);

  return { expand, toggle };
};
```

`OtherComponent.js`

```
const OtherComponent = () => {
  const { expand, toggle } = useAccord(false);

  return <div className={`Accord`} onClick={toggle}></div>;
};
```

Ref:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

generally you can declare a function in parent component and pass it as a props to child component. now if you invoke it in child component, function execute in parent.

this concept can be developed with props, context, redux